# Google Sheets - ARRAYFORMULA combined with MATCH back-range search

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, counting, countif

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15q3iMg2D9KQmmmYVeqz0g7qX1pK3nf_mTiAFmTEoqyo/edit?usp=sharing

I have a problem with the use of ARRAYFORMULA together with MATCH in Google Sheets:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A10,A$1:A9, 0)), "Not found", "Found")
```

Basically I would like to do something like that:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A10:A,A$1:A9, 0)), "Not found", "Found"))
```

The problem is following part: **A$1:A9** as I do not know how to limit the range of search for MATCH just to the previous records within arrayformula. I would need to search within the range lower than **A10**).

Is there any possibility to use something like "back range" in array formula combined with MATCH searches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A=IF(,,),,
 IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))>1, 
 "Found", "Not Found")))
```

[image]

Comment: While searching in range: R10647:R it will always be "Found" in such range, because I'm looking for R10648. I would like to do the search within R:R10647 (previous records) if is it a duplicate.

Comment: @mishelles can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: Sure, It will illustrate the case: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15q3iMg2D9KQmmmYVeqz0g7qX1pK3nf_mTiAFmTEoqyo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @mishelles answer updated